Multiplicative structure of cohomology theories of weighted projective bundles?
This question is about multiplicative structure of cohomology theories of weighted projective bundles.
I have been working on this subject during many years. Since I retired (around 2017's), I stopped looking seriously for such a cohomolgy multiplicative structure, via associated weighted Chern classes I defined in my work: published in "Algebraic Geometry, LNPAM volume 193, edited by Sinan Sertöz (Marcel Dekker INC 1997 (pp. 1-52)).
I would like to know if this multiplicative structure is now known (partially? completely?).

Link to a Google Books preview of the start of your article: https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Algebraic_Geometry/DJ73zhxf9SIC?hl=en&gbpv=1
